# Shifter with stuck barrel adjuster

Tags: shifter

I've been looking for a solution on this but couldn't find anything online. I have an Alfine 8 speed internal gear hub and it started skipping recently. I tried to use the barrel adjuster on the shifter to adjust, but the barrel adjuster got stuck and it won't turn in any direction anymore. Is there a way to fix this? I can still pull the barrel adjuster slightly (as if I am about to make an adjustment), and can turn in both directions a couple of millimetres, but it does not go forward more than that. Can I solve it by any means or should I just replace the shifter? This is the shifter by the way:

[http://www.amazon.com/SHIMANO-SHIFTER-SL-S503-ALFINE-2100mmCABLE/dp/B00KV9SJ2Q/ref=sr_1_16?s=sporting-goods&ie=UTF8&qid=1460402799&sr=1-16&keywords=alfine+shifter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KV9SJ2Q)

Thanks!

Comment: On some shifters of that style the adjuster has a spring and sort of ratchet mechanism in it, and you must pull the adjuster barrel out to turn it.

Comment: I can pull it out slightly, but it still doesn't turn around. I used to adjust it like that though, by pulling it out and turning.

Comment: Is it possible that some dirt has gotten in there?

Comment: Could be, but I didn't really ride in a dirty condition recently (And I can't see any dirt; I also clean the bike almost every week). Could something like a WD40 work in that case? I suspect that somehow I tightened it too much and it somehow does not work anymore but is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pliers and turning the barrel adjuster counter-clockwise worked.

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 3):

You can install an inline cable adjuster. There are several companies that make them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, but I'm still curious about what's wrong with mine and whether it's fixable or not.